# Gekko error " Results files not found. APM did not find a solution or the server is unreachable"

Tags: python, gekko

I follow course on this site:
https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization

I tried some Gekko script and get same error:

```
     Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.429999999527354E-002 sec
 Objective      :    17.0140172891559     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2005, in solve
    results = byte2str(get_file(self._server,self._model_name,'results.json'))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gekko\apm.py", line 160, in get_file
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/CIVIL/LePy/le_Gekko1.py", line 44, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2022, in solve
    raise ImportError('Results files not found. APM did not find a solution or the server is unreachable.')
ImportError: Results files not found. APM did not find a solution or the server is unreachable.
```

How can I fix it? 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you modify the question with more details about the problem you are trying to solve? It isn't possible to give you a specific answer with the information that you provided. Some general suggestions are to (1) set the display option to True as ```m.solve(disp=True)``` and (2) to try a local solve with remote set to False as ```m = GEKKO(remote=False)``` so that it doesn't rely on an Internet connection.

Comment: John Hedengren, thank you! I think on my laptop, something in GEKKO were wrong, because which this code - a simple example, this time it run okey but another time it can't.

Comment: The error says that it either didn't find a solution or that the server is not reachable. If you follow the two suggestions above, you should be able to find the reason it had an error.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, with GEKKO(remote=False), this error was fix. Thank you. PS: I'm not permitted to voice  :(

Comment: John Hedengren, would you give me some example to approach me learn how to use the MPC in GEKKO for optimate 2 input variable (with some constrain) and 1 target output (Multi reservoir operation issue). Thank you!

Comment: There are many examples of MPC at https://apmonitor.com/do  You may also want to try the documentation at https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ where additional examples are posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem solved successfully but there is an error after the solution completed then it is likely that there was a problem retrieving the solution file from the compute server. You can eliminate the dependency on a remote server if you set the option `remote` to `False`:

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
```

You can see the results.csv file (solution file) in the run directory by opening the folder.

```py
m.open_folder()
```